# Send file by jquery ajax to a CodeIgniter Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need to "send" a file (from a form) and other data to a codeigniter controller, using ajax. Something like this:

```
 $("#formuploadajax").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var f = $(this);
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formuploadajax"));
        formData.append("dato", "valor");
        //formData.append(f.attr("name"), $(this)[0].files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "example/examplerecibe.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "html",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
     processData: false
        })
            .done(function(res){
                $("#mensaje").html("Respuesta: " + res);
            });
    });
     ...
```

The codeigniter controller validatew the file and other data, and then creates the file in the respective folder.

I try with a lot of code from stackoverflow -and other sites-, and nothing works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me after many attempts.

I push all code (html, js y the controller -php-):

The View and the script:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" class="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- add your span and pther stuff here-->
        <input type="file" id="foto1" name="userfile" />
        <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="submitFile();" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pathArray = "<?php print base_url(); ?>";
</script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    function submitFile(){
        var formUrl = "url of your php";
        var formData = new FormData($('.myForm')[0]);

        $.ajax({
           url:pathArray+'creacion/crearSolicitud/do_upload',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data){

alert("bien");
                },
                error: function(jqXHR){
                      //   var result = JSON.parse(query);

alert("mal");
                }
        });
}

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and the CodeIgniter:

```
    public function do_upload()
    {
        //Condicion de que sea una entrada tipo AJAX:
        if(!$this->input->is_ajax_request())
        {
            echo json_encode("jaja");
        }
        else
        {   

$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        //$config['max_size']   = '1000000';
        //$config['max_width']  = '10240';
        //$config['max_height']  = '768000';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            echo json_encode($error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
echo json_encode($data);
        }
```

With this, I can create a file without refresh the page, only send a message.

Answer (score 0):

Well i have implemented that

```
function uploadfile() {
        var input = document.getElementById("photoid");
        file = input.files[0];
        if (file != undefined) {
            formData = new FormData();
            if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
                formData.append("image", file);
                $('#loader').fadeIn();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://example.com",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#loader").fadeOut(1000);
                        if (data == 1) {
                           //success
                        }
                        else {
                            //error
                        }
                    }
                });

            } else {
                alert('Please select an image');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Please Select Image!');
        }
    } ;
```